# WHERE not found in LINQ query

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to write a program that takes car details from a .csv file and then adds each cars specific details to a list object.

I am having trouble using a LINQ query to find all cars in the list that have a certain make value of `CITROEN`.

It is giving me the error:

> Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'CarList'.  'Where' not found.

It is also saying this on my `foreach`:

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type '?' because '?' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'

What am i doing wrong. I have followed a Microsoft page about how to use LINQ and I don't understand the error.

This is my program class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqPractical
{
    class Program
    {
        static CarList carList = new CarList();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car car = new Car();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"F:\\motfailures.csv"));
            string header = reader.ReadLine();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                var values = line.Split(',');

                car.Make = values[0];
                car.Model = values[1];
                car.Year = values[2];
                car.Pass = values[3];
                car.Fail = values[4];

                carList.Add(car);

                Console.WriteLine("Added car to list with details:");
                Console.WriteLine("Make: " + values[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("Model: " + values[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("Year: " + values[2]);
                Console.WriteLine("Pass: " + values[3]);
                Console.WriteLine("Fail: " + values[4]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

            ShowMake();
        }

        public static void ShowMake()
        {

            var query = from car in carList
                           where car.Make == "CITROEN"
                           select car;

            foreach (Car c in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Make: " + c.Make + " Model: " + c.Model + " Year: " + c.Year);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

List class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqPractical
{
    class CarList
    {
        private List<Car> _list = new List<Car>();

        public void Add(Car newCar)
        {
            _list.Add(newCar);
        }
    }
}
```

and car class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinqPractical
{
    public class Car
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;
        private string _year;
        private string _pass;
        private string _fail;

        public string Make
        {
            get
            {
                return _make;
            }
            set
            {
                _make = value;
            }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get
            {
                return _model;
            }
            set
            {
                _model = value;
            }
        }

        public string Year
        {
            get
            {
                return _year;
            }
            set
            {
                _year = value;
            }
        }

        public string Pass
        {
            get
            {
                return _pass;
            }
            set
            {
                _pass = value;
            }
        }

        public string Fail
        {
            get
            {
                return _fail;
            }
            set
            {
                _fail = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `where car.Make == "CITROEN"` *with* quotes. It is a string you are comparing it to, not a variable or field or property.

Comment: I tried this but i still get the same errors

Comment: Not part of your question, but you're creating ONE single car and overwrite the values for each line and add this one car multiple times to your list. You should create you car object inside foreach loop.

Comment: The other main issue is that `CarList` is not enumerable. You do not need to create your own type here, just delete that type from your code and use `List<Car>` instead.

Comment: … and you can simplify you Car class using properties without backing fields (public string Model {get;set;}).

Comment: `Car car = new Car();` should be in the while loop, you are adding the same instance multiple times which will just be the same one which ever it did last.

Comment: In order for making your code work with LINQ, your collection class (`CarList`) must implement everything LINQ needs.  If you implement `IEnumerable<T>` (or, more appropriately, `IList<T>` it should just work.  Or, better still, get rid of the `CarList` class and just use a `List<Car>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq cannot operate on any class. It can only deal with classes, that represent a typed list by implementing `IEnumerable<T>`

So either you define `public class CarList : IEnumerable<Car>` and implement the interface yourself, or you just extend the List-class like `public class CarList : List<Car>`, where you then do not need the class field any more.

Comment: Nitpick: LINQ can work with classes that don't implement `IEnumerable<T>`.  They can work with any class that provides all the functions it needs.  However, if you implement `IEnumerable<T>` you get them via the extension methods on that interface.  Doing it by hand would not be much fun.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is because your CarList class does not implement IEnumerable.   Igor's comment about using the List is the right way to go unless you need specific functionality that creating your own list type would provide.   Don't over-architect the solution if you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

The code confusing/miss leading as you added a method (add) which just adds to an internal list.

You car list class `CarList` is not a list of cars its an container which contain a list of cars.

So the reason you are getting the error is you are trying to interact on the container `CarList` which is not enumerable. You should be interacting on the `List<Car>` this stems from poor naming... your `CarList` is more like `CarProviderA` which has a list of cars.

wont work

```
 var query = from car in carList -- not a list of cars
             where car.Make == "CITROEN"
             select car;
```

will work

```
 var query = from car in carList.List  -- where List is a public property of _list to the list of cars
             where car.Make == "CITROEN"
             select car;
```

Also

```
Car car = new Car();
```

should be in the while loop, you are adding the same instance multiple times which will just be the same one which ever it did last.

***Should look something like this***

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    Car car = new Car(); 
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    car.Make = values[0];
    car.Model = values[1];
    car.Year = values[2];
    car.Pass = values[3];
    car.Fail = values[4];

    carList.Add(car);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's answered in the comments, but just to provide some code…

In most cases you don't need separate fields for your properties. Removing them will drastically improve readability of your code:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Now just use the generic List and remove your CarList class (that's the problem why you get errors in your code):

```
var carList = new List<Car>();
```

You want to add one care per line, so let's create one per line. I'd suggest to use a more compact way to write this (again: easier to read):

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',');

    carList.Add(new Car {
      Make = values[0],
      Model = values[1]
    });
}
```